# Actionscript - obtain method list for a given class name

Tags: class, reflection, actionscript, methods

I want to obtain a list of methods available to a class, given its name. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called introspection, and AS3 has a limited ability to do introspection.

Here is about the best you can do,

```
import flash.utils.describeType;

var data:XML = (describeType(SingleEvent));
for each (var method:XML in data.factory.method) {
    trace("Name: " + method.@name);
    trace("Returns: " + method.@returnType);
    for each (var parameter:XML in method.children()) {
        trace("Parameter " + parameter.@index + ": " + parameter.@type + ", optional: " + parameter.@optional);
    }
    trace("----------------------------");
}
```

Unfortunately, this is the limitation and will only be able to show you methods with public accessors.  You can look at the output of

```
print data.toXMLString()
```

as well, to see what else is available for viewing.